# foreign key of sql scripts generated by visual studio are different

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two Entity classes :

```
public class User 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetail
{
    public string Biography { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And the DbContext is :

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext (DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserDetail> UserDetails { get; set; }
}
```

When I run command :

> dotnet ef migrations add Initial
>
> dotnet ef database update

The two tables will be generated . When I double click the "dbo.UserDetails" within the "SQL Server Object Explorer" of Visual Studio , there's a foreign key shown in Design View :

[image: Foreign Key in Design View]

However , If right click the "dbo.UserDetails" , and choose "Script As" -> "Create To" -> "New Query Window" , the generated sql will be :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserDetails] (
    [Biography] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [UserId]    NVARCHAR (450) NOT NULL
);
```

What make me confused is that the FK CONSTRAINT is gone away here.

- Visual Studio : community 2017 , 15.7.5
- .NET Core SDK : 2.1.302
- Entity Framework Core : 2.1.1-rtm-30846

Any helps ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: A constraint can be included in the table definition's `CREATE` script, but it is not formally part of the table. It creates a separate object that happens to be associated with the table. Apparently, the default script action doesn't include FK constraints. In Management Studio, there is a separate "Generate Scripts" tasks where you can configure whether or not to include constraints and indexes; I'm not sure if the VS Object Explorer has something similar. (I'm pretty sure Management Studio would not omit the *primary* key when scripting, though, and you'll notice that even that's gone!)

Comment: I have just tried this in VS2017 15.8.3 and the foreign keys and indexes are scripted out. As suggested by @JeroenMostert there are options in Management Studio for what gets scripted by default though I could not find these in VS

Comment: I'm having this problem too, I'm not able to add an FK without a PK

Comment: @mheptinstall I just test it with Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (15.8.3) , it makes no difference . The FK only "exists" when I inspect the table in Design View .

Comment: @JeroenMostert  Thanks  ! I test it with SSMS v 17.9 and the FK contraints is right there . It seems a bug of VS Object Explorer

Comment: @Charanoglu Well, it turns out actually the FK is already there while we cannot see them by mistake .  PoC : if I execute sql command by executing  "insert into UserDetail 
 (Biography,UserId) 
values 
 ('hello,wrold','here is user id FK')" in Visual Studio , it will  complain that "Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UserDetail_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "App-EFCore-FK-Test", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated."  . This proves that the FK exists already .

Comment: @JeroenMostert , Thanks again ! Would you mind writing a answer so that I can accept it as answer ? It may help other guys who run into a similar situation .