# Cannot define a table without PK

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a table called `AspNetUsers` which is the default table created by `AspNetCore.Identity`, I created a class called `User` which inherit `IdentityUser` and implement more field on `AspNetUsers`:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string LockoutMessage { get; set; }
    public string SessionId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserDetails UserDetail { get; set; }
}
```

then I created another class called `UserDetails`, I don't need the `PK` in this table, because in `UserDetails` I need to store the details of the user available in `User` which is the `AspNetUsers` table:

```
public class UserDetails
{
    //public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Biography { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string FacebookLink { get; set; }
    public string TwitterLink { get; set; }
    public string SkypeLink { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I uncomment the `Id` property the migration works well, but I don't need the `Id` so I commented the property and execute this command:

```
add-migration Initial-Migration -context DemoAppContext
update-database
```

inside the `DemoAppContext` class I told to `EF` to implement the `FK` on `UserDetails`:

```
public class DemoAppContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DemoAppContext(DbContextOptions<DemoAppContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(d => d.UserDetail)
                  .WithOne(p => p.User)
                  .HasForeignKey<UserDetails>(x => x.UserId);
        });
    }

    public DbSet<UserDetails> UserDetails { get; set; }
}
```

after the `Add-Migration` command I get this error:

> The entity type 'UserDetails' requires a primary key to be defined.

As I said if I commented out the `Id` all works well, but I don't need a `PK` on `UserDetails`.

Comment: If there's only one `UserDetails` per `User`, isn't `UserId` the primary key?

Comment: You don't need this primary key, but EF6 does :) It doesn't break anything, let it be there auto-increment. Still, I don't understand why you would need another table for exact 1-to-1 user-to-details matching.

Comment: @JacobKrall yes, I specified the `key` inside the `OnModelCreating`, perhaps I missing something? And for @Yeldar, is just an organization

Comment: @Charanoglu What Jacob probably meant is make `UserId` the primary key of UserDetails in addition to it being a foreign key.

Comment: @ckuri How can I do this? Shouldn't EF recognize the Id attached to the property name?

Comment: It should be `builder.Entity<UserDetails>().HasKey(entity => entity.UserId)` or put the `[Key]` attribute above UserId.

Comment: @ckuri wait, how can know the `AspNetUsers` table to bound the `UserId` of `UserDetails` if in your code you only specified the `UserDetails`?

Comment: You are already extending the IdentityUser class so why not just put the UserDetails properties in the User class.  You're over-complicating your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I said if I commented out the Id all works well, but I don't need a PK on UserDetails

If I understand correctly , you just don't want to add an extra column (for example, `Id` or `UserDetailsId` ) set as the PK . The `UserDetails` table that you want to create will have a `UserId` which references the `User` table , and the `UserId` will serve as PK and FK at the same time .

In fact , there's no need to have an `Id` property for `UserDetails` entity . So why your code does not work ? The reason is that you mixed up the dependent entity and the principal entity .

The prototype of [`HasForeignKey<>()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.referencereferencebuilder-2.hasforeignkey?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_ReferenceReferenceBuilder_2_HasForeignKey__1_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Object___) is:

```
public virtual ReferenceReferenceBuilder<TEntity,TRelatedEntity> HasForeignKey<TDependentEntity> 
    (
        Expression<Func<TDependentEntity,object>> foreignKeyExpression
    ) 
    where TDependentEntity : class;
```

Note the generic parameter of `HasForeignKey<TDependentEntity>()` represents the dependent entity .

And here's the code of yours :

```
builder.Entity<User>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.UserDetail)
            .WithOne(p => p.User)
        .HasForeignKey<UserDetails>(x => x.UserId);
});
```

See that ? In your code , the `entity` here is `User` , which is the Principal Entity instead of the Dependent Entity .  To fix it , change your code as below :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<User>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasOne(u => u.UserDetail).WithOne(d => d.User);
    });

    builder.Entity<UserDetails>(entity =>
    {
        // set the UserId as key
        entity.HasKey(d=>d.UserId);

        // the relationship between `UserDetails : User`  is  1-to-1
        entity.HasOne(d=>d.User).WithOne(u=>u.UserDetail)
            // set column `UserId` as the FK for the dependent entity , i.e. , the `UserDetails` .
            .HasForeignKey<UserDetails>(u=>u.UserId); 
    });
}
```

It will generate a `UserDetails` table with the `UserId` column set as the PrimaryKey and the ForeignKey at the same time :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserDetails] (
    [Biography]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Country]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [FacebookLink] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [TwitterLink]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SkypeLink]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [UserId]       NVARCHAR (450) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_UserDetails_AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

By the way , there seems a bug in SQL Server Object Explorer of Visual Studio (see [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319510/foreign-key-of-sql-scripts-generated-by-visual-studio-are-different)) , resulting in a mistake that we cannot see the already existing FK contrains .

However , we can prove it by trying to insert a row with a non-existing UserId :

```
insert into UserDetails 
    (Biography,UserId) 
values 
    ('hello,wrold','here-is-a-non-existing-user-id')
```

It will complains the following message as expected :

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UserDetail_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "App-EFCore-FK-Test", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
>
> The statement has been terminated.